# GLMM with ex-Gaussian distribution function (trial-level reaction time data)

Tags: r, distributions, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I am trying to use GLMM in R to fit a mixed-effects model (three categorical predictors, one continuous predictor) to trial-level reaction times from a group of participants.

The reaction time distributions (for the sample, experimental groups, and each participant) are ex-Gaussian in shape. From reading and searching the internet, it doesn't seem possible to specify an ex-Gaussian distribution with the `family` argument of the `glmer()` function (as would be possible with other distributional functions like `family = binomial()`).

I would like to ask if there might be a way to **fit the mixed-effects model using `glmer()` and an ex-Gaussian distribution**, or if there might be **other (non-Bayesian) functions I could use instead.**

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is indeed not possible to fit such a model with `glmer()`. As an alternative, you can try my **[GLMMadaptive](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/)** package that allows you to define your own distribution for the mixed model. An example of how to do this can be found [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html).